# Docker error getting username from password database

Tags: python, python-2.7, docker

I have a python script which i would like to containerized

test_remote.py

```
import os
import pwd
try:
    userid = pwd.getpwuid(os.stat('.').st_uid).pw_name
except KeyError, err:
    raise Exception('NIS Problem: userid lookup failed: %s' % err)
print "Hi, I am %s" % userid
```

which runs fine

```
[eugene@mymachine workdir]# python test_remote.py 
Hi, I am eugene
```

To run this script in a container, I wrote the following Dockerfile

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:2.7-slim

WORKDIR /data

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /data

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /data/requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "/data/br-release/bin/test_remote.py"]
```

When I run the image, it's not able to do a lookup.

```
[eugene@mymachine workdir]# docker run -v testremote
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/test_remote.py", line 27, in <module>
    raise Exception('NIS Problem: userid lookup failed: %s' % err)
Exception: NIS Problem: userid lookup failed: 'getpwuid(): uid not found: 52712'
```

I've tried to create a user and run it as via adding the following lines in Dockerfile

```
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash eugene
USER eugene
```

but i am still getting the error lookup failed error

Any suggestions?
how would I get "eugene" from test_remote.py if I don't do a look up against password database. I suppose one way would be set USERNAME as an env var and have the script parse that.

Comment: What command did you run? The issue is that there is no mapping name for the uid inside the docker image and that is causing the issue. See this thread for a similar issue related to group https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46204643/is-there-any-way-to-specify-the-group-name-and-id-for-a-group-with-docker-run/46205239#46205239

Comment: @TarunLalwani what do you mean what command did i run? it's a python code "userid = pwd.getpwuid(os.stat('.').st_uid).pw_name" and okay ill take a look at that question

Comment: No, I meant how you ran your docker container?

Comment: ah, i built the image as "docker build -t testremote" and then ran "docker run testremote"

Answer (score 4):

This is your problem:

```
userid lookup failed: 'getpwuid(): uid not found: 52712'
```

Inside your Docker container, there is no user with UID 52712.  You can create one explicitly when you build the image:

```
RUN useradd -u 52712 -ms /bin/bash eugene
```

Or you can mount `/etc/passwd` from your host when you run it:

```
docker run -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd ...
```

Comment: thank you @larsks is there a way to do it so that 52712 isnt hard-coded inside Dockerfile so the container could be used for any users? i will tried mounting /etc/passwd. that may work for any users

Comment: Right, just mounting /etc/passwd will work for most cases. There are other ways of tackling this problem (e.g., pass the user id in as a variable and have an `ENYTRPOINT` script create the user at runtime...) but they are less convenient.